# Different layouts for different post types in wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

What is the reason behind allowing developers to create page templates so easily and not allowing the same for posts?

I have 2 custom post type named **Mathematics** and **Mechanical** I made it using the below function.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'math_tuts',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Mathematics' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'maths' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
  register_post_type( 'mech_tuts',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Mechanical' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'mech' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

I want to give a full width layout and CSS styling for **Mathematics** and I want a different CSS styling and sidebar for **Mechanical**. I know I can do this by using plugins but I want to avoid them and build this from scratch. How can I create different layouts such that Mechanical and Mathematics do not pick up the styling from **single.php**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the custom post type term to the single.php

In your case, create new files `single-mathematics.php` and `single-mechanical.php`

Copy the `single.php` code, paste in these files and edit it for full-width/no-sidebar. WordPress will automatically search for these files when the custom post type page is loaded.